# Spawn Mobs With Specific Items Equipped

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

**Hi All,**
In *MCPE 1.16.2*, I want to create a way in which when I eat a specific item (call that ‘alpha’), it spawns 4 mobs with a helmet equipped. And also would it be possible to make the mobs work for me, so when a player attacks me, the mobs attack the offender? I’m specifically trying to make these commands in one
**.mcfunction** file and not multiple command blocks